# Dudas sobre como guardar texto introducido por teclado en un vector separado por comas

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar una parte de un proyecto en la cual tengo que introducir por teclado un texto, por ejemplo: `CentroC,Partido5,455`.

Este texto tiene que estar separado por comas y guardado en un vector, he visto cosas por internet pero no acabo de solucionar de la manera que yo lo tengo.

```
public class Resultados
{/*Clase*/
    private String tripleta;

    //Vamos a crear el constructor.

    public Resultados(String n) {

        tripleta= n;    
    }

    public String getTripleta()
    {
        return tripleta;
    }

    public void setTripleta(String tripleta)
    {
        this.tripleta = tripleta;
    }



}/*Clase*/
```

---

```
   case 3:
                                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion Resultados");
                                System.out.println("");
                                System.out.println("");
                                leer.nextLine(); //Vaciar el bufer sino salta todo el for.
                                for(int i=0;i<resultados.length;i++)
                                {

                                    System.out.println("Introduce la tripleta con centro, partido y numero de votos.");
                                    System.out.println("");
                                    tripleta=leer.nextLine();//Vamos a guardar el nombre en la variable
                                    leer.nextLine();
                                    resultados[i]=new Resultados(tripleta);// Guardamos los datos dentro del vector.

                                }
```

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido. Por favor, di que resultado o comportamiento que tiene tu programa , cual deberia ser , si hay algun error o no...

Answer (score 0):

Para mantener el array de tipo *Resultados*, pero almacenar por separado los valores que introduce el usuario en tres *String* distintos, podrías modificar el objeto *Resultados* para que contenga los tres parámetros de tipo *String* y que el propio constructor reciba la cadena separada por comas y le haga el split. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Resultados {
    private String centro;
    private String partido;
    private String votos;

    public Resultados(String tripleta) {
        String[] parts = tripleta.split("-");
        centro = parts[0];
        partido = parts[1];
        votos = parts[2];
    }
}
```